# Current support on Android for playing multiple audio tracks at a time using the html5 audio tag

Tags: android, html, audio

I'm writing an html5 / javascript game and have read a lot on various blog posts about iOS only being able to play one audio track at any one time using the html5 audio tag. That seems to have been fixed in iOS6 but what I don't see a lot of information about is what support is like on Android. I have a couple of Android devices - a Samsung Galaxy Nexus running Jelly Bean (v4.2.1) and a Kindle Fire running the latest version (10.2.4) which I think is an adapted version of Ice Cream Sandwich. The galaxy nexus will only play one track at any time but the Kindle Fire will play multiple. I'm assuming this is down to the fact that the Silk browser on Kindle Fire has better support for the audio tag than the default Android browser but I wanted to confirm that so I can try and gauge how much of an impact the issue will have.

Here's the code that doesn't work properly on the Galaxy Nexus:

```
<audio id="audio1" controls>
    <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/cat.m4a" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/cat.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio><br />
<audio id="audio2" controls>
    <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/song.m4a" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio><br />
<button onclick="play();">Play</button><br />

<script type='text/javascript'>

var play = function() {
    var audio1 = document.getElementById('audio1');
    var audio2 = document.getElementById('audio2');
    audio1.play();
    audio2.play(); // this will stop audio1 on the Galaxy Nexus
}

</script>
```

Do other android devices running either Ice Cream Sandwich or Jelly Bean only support one track at a time?

[This web page](http://jsfiddle.net/aarongloege/gzLAe/embedded/result/) gives a good quick test. if you click Play, both should play together. I'm particularly interested in devices that run proprietary software on top of Android rather than just the "pure" Android which is on the Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

The page that you commented above, doesn't work in a native Android 4.1.2 browser. I heard about the Web Audio API, but it has many restrictions to run in various browsers for the Android Plataform.

I know that HTML5 Audio and Web Audio API doesn't work well in different mobile browsers.

But I found a solution about run multiple audio using HTML5 in this project: **[*lycheejs.org*](http://lycheejs.org/index.html)** mantained by Christoph Martens, but don't have any forum or something similar to discuss about (at least I don't have found). Actually, **[*cosmo.lycheejs*](http://cosmo.lycheejs.org/index.html)** is one example that is possible to run multiple audio in the same time in Android Plataform. However this is possible only in Firefox. Chrome and Navite Android browser don't work. See this video: **www.youtube.com/watch?v=PojeyUiFLi4**

if someone could make an example using this solution please reply here.

See these websites to understand the complexity to run multiple audio in the same time in mobile browsers:

**www.codetheory.in/html5-audio-behaviour-and-support-in-ios-and-android/**

**www.codetheory.in/solve-your-game-audio-problems-on-ios-and-android-with-web-audio-api/**

Comment: Chrome fixed this issue in the new Chrome BETA for Android. Download **[_Chrome BETA_](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta&hl=en)** and test this **[_example_](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/midi-synth/index.html)**. I didn't find a solution yet for Navite Android browser.